# Below grade wall rotted - will this solution work?

Tags: foundation, waterproofing, carpentry, crawlspace

looking for a little guidance if my solution will work here.

One section of my 1830s simply has a crawlspace underneath, and it seems that in the rear the sill plate simply rests on top of a constructed wood foundation, which in turn makes contact with rock-heavy soil. This supporting wall is constructed just like any other - what I understand to be the sill plate acts as the top plate of the wall, with studs, a base plate, and boards on the exterior side. Here's a simply drawing I did to help explain, and I apologize if I'm using the wrong terms (please correct me as I try to learn):

[image]

The previous owner had placed pink fiberglass batts between the studs (there are exterior boards on the other side of the studs), and tried to seal it in with plastic stapled to the wood. Evidently they did not wrap the bottom of the bottom plate well, and it allowed moisture into behind the plastic wrap. The fiberglass batts soaked up the moisture, and rotted 7 feet of the bottom plate and the bottom 3-5 inches of some of the studs. Picture below:

[image]

Just to the left of this picture would be the support post and footer. From everything I can tell, there is piled earth on the other side of this wall at least half way up.

My plan is to support the wall with temporary 2x4 supports under the top plate, remove the remainder of the rotted bottom plate, wrap plastic sheeting around the outer sides of the plate and install a new one, and cut out the rot/sister new studs to the old ones. Should I try to excavate the dirt on the other side of the wall (from the inside) to alleviate wood contact with earth, or leave as is and wrap the bottom plate as best I can? Or is there a better way that I can approach this?